# Phonegap modify config.xml for NSAppTransportSecurity

Tags: ios, xml, cordova, plist

I have a next issue, i have to add NSAppTransportSecurity key into my info.plist file.

Because i have many different config.xml for Test, Development and Production servers it is not good to add NSAppTransportSecurity key into plist manually.

Could this be done inside the config.xml itself?

I have tried this:

```
<manifest device="ios" tag="plist/dict">
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
        ...
        </dict>
    </array>

    <!--Here is my own:-->
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</manifest>
```

But after cordova build iOS i get this in my info.plist:

```
<key>[object Object]</key>
<string>NSAppTransportSecurity</string>
```

But the CFBundleURLTypes gets ported normally. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: just add platform to ios

Comment: then use the default info.plist file to access

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cordova-custom-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config) plugin to achieve this:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

then add to config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSAppTransportSecurity">
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with DaveAlden's solution. But if `NSAppTransportSecurity` is the only thing you are interested in manipulating in `*-Info.plist` file, then you can use [cordova-ios-security plugin](https://github.com/robertklein/cordova-ios-security)

This plugin takes care of the job which you were doing manually in `*-Info.plist` file